# Database security in NoSQL environments

Tags: nosql, database-security

In traditional DBMSs we can see security mechanisms like access control implemented using SQL. In NoSQL environments, how are such security mechanisms implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can say that nosql is under developing face so there is some issue related to Security,

but some databases is providing security mechanism itself like [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/)

and some are in developement face so need to wait for them.